# Problems sending MMS

Tags: mms

I am unable to receive or send multi media messages using my Samsung Galaxy Ace plus.
When I send a MMS it gets stuck and when I receive a picture or form of media from a friend (e.g. my friend has an iPhone and has tried to send me pictures however my Samsung is unable to open these.

Comment: Maybe you don't have correct MMS setting for you carrier. By not able to open the MMS you received, you mean the MMS downloads fine but doesn't open?

Comment: Do you receive them on your device and simply cannot open them -- or do you not even receive them? Maybe you need to check your MMS APN settings and compare with what your provider/carrier needs.